# Unable to click on hologram level to view imperial objectives after moving under construction imperial level

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I learned earlier today that you can move imperial levels to a lower number floor to change the required items for completing an imperial objective. I had an imperial level under construction and I moved it to floor -1. Now I'm unable to click on the hologram level to view my current objectives. Will this fix itself when the floor in done construction? I'm just scared I broke my game.

Comment: Very odd.  I've moved levels to that position without a problem.  Did you exit the game and reopen it??

Comment: I only exited the game after having this problem to fix it but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: was any of the floors you moved under construction?

Comment: I don't recall if it was under construction when I moved it.  I have moved plenty of under construction regular floors, though.  Wait for it to finish building and let us know if it changes.  Also, does it significantly change the required amounts for each mission?  I never tried that . . .

Comment: Okay after the time finished I could access the hologram level. It had the same amount of required items. However the next objective is a complete joke. I need 20 Battle droids which take 4.5 hours each. Next time I get a mover droid ill defiantly be moving it

Comment: Put an answer in for the question when you can.  And, I'm glad to hear it worked!

Answer (score 2):

So after the construction finished I was able to re-access the hologram level with the new item I put there with no change to the required stock.